# How to read a file directly written using fwrite by double clicking it

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am writing the values of the following 1-D array in a file(text file) but when I open it by double clicking it, it's not readable. Why so?? Also please tell me the solution so that I can write a file(text file) and read it by double clicking it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{FILE *fp;
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
fp=fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
fwrite(a, sizeof(int), 5, fp);
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: you want to write the ascii value of the numbers, not the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters are represented in ASCII - a numeric value.
When declaring the array with 1 to 5 and writing it with `fwrite()` you meant "write the characters represented here" and not the numbers, which will mean it will treat it as the character with that ASCII value.
If you wanted to write the character `1` you should have written `'1'` to declare it as a character and say you're using the ASCII of it (the ASCII of '1' is 49).
This is the ASCII table:
http://www.asciitable.com/
If you'd look at the ASCII table at these values you'd see these characters are not a regular ones, you can't SEE them, they have no font or something - it's just usually for the computer itself. For example, ending strings with NULL (which ASCII is 0).
You tried to write SOH for example when trying to write the first element and so on.
To correct your code you should put two apostrophes, one from each side of number to declare it as a digit, a character, the following way:

```
int a[5] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
```

and using an int is only using 4 bytes for nothing, as you can see you have up to 256 characters, which can be represented in one byte (one byte - 8 bits - 2^8 = 256 values that can be represented in one byte) so you'd declare:

```
char a[5] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
```

to save up some memory.

Answer (score 2):

fwrite writes the binary values to the file.  If you're writing text values, you probably want to use fprintf instead.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    fp=fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
    for( int i=0; i<5; ++i )
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", a[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

See:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the literal numbers 1-5 to the file, which are probably just not displayed properly by whatever program you use for that.

If you want to write the characters corresponding to "1" - "5" use `fprintf` or an fstream.